# update a row of mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying to update my table 'total':

in the row of id = 1, I want to update the value of 'days_left' to be 47.

```
String values_to_update = "UPDATE total SET days_left = '47' where id = '1'";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "Admin");
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(values_to_update);
con.close();
```

Why isn't it updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least, you need to execute your SQL statement via : `ps.executeUpdate();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the prepared statement.
Try:

```
ps.executeUpdate(); 
con.commit();
```

before you close the connection.

Comment: I tried it and it works.. but, now I got an error: "Can't call commit when autocommit=true".

Comment: Remove the commit line then and accept my response, or the one above or below, at your discretion.

Answer (score 1):

Do ...

```
ps.executeUpdate()
```

... before you close the connection. It doesn't look like you need a prepared statement either. A statement will do in your case.